# In GraphQL, How to select field with condition that same feature appears more than once

Tags: graphql

I have a dataset with a scheme like this:

```
{
orders{
    consumer{
        _id,
        name
            }
    }
}
```

My query is :

```
 query{
      orders{
            customer{
          _id
        }
      }
    }
```

And I am given:

```
{
  "data": {
    "orders": [
      { 
        "amount" : 12345,
        "customer": {
          "_id": "aaaaaaaaa"
        }
      },
      {
        "amount" : 12324,
        "customer": {
          "_id": "aaaaaaaaaa"
        }
      },
      {
        "amount" : 12385,
        "customer": {
          "_id": "bbbbbbbbbb"
        }
      },
      { 
        "amount" : 12245,
        "customer": {
          "_id": "cccccccccc"
        }
      }
      {
        "amount" : 12349,
        "customer": {
          "_id": "cccccccccc"
        }
      }, ... ]
    }
 }
```

I would like to return all orders with the same customer_id appears more than one. So the desired return would be :

```
{
  "data": {
    "orders": [
      { 
        "amount" : 12345,
        "customer": {
          "_id": "aaaaaaaaa"
        }
      },
      {
        "amount" : 12324,
        "customer": {
          "_id": "aaaaaaaaaa"
        }
      },
      { 
        "amount" : 12245,
        "customer": {
          "_id": "cccccccccc"
        }
      }
      {
        "amount" : 12349,
        "customer": {
          "_id": "cccccccccc"
        }
      }, ... ]
    }
 }
```

So the order for custmer_id = "bbbbbbbb" has to be eliminated since this customer_id appears only once.

How to write the GraphQL query?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to return all orders with the same customer_id appears more than one. ...

> So the order for custmer_id = "bbbbbbbb" has to be eliminated since this customer_id appears only once.

> How to write the GraphQL query?

**graphql is not for that**

Filtering, searching, counting ... is **out of graphql specs**. There is **no standarized params or syntax for this requirements**.

**It's resolver role to perform actions/bussiness logic** [in reaction on some parameters/variables - data-driven actions].

In this case you can use some 'filter flag', f.e. 'recurringOnly' (not required, false default), for 'orders' resolver. When query will contain `true` value for this flag:

```
query{
  orders(recurringOnly: true) {
```

... resolver should filter out non-recurring entries ... how? depends on server/service implementation details/DB/ORM/libs/whatever used to resolve data/results.